# Ubuntu 18.10 constantly freezing and filesystem gets corrupted

Tags: filesystem, crash, read-only

**EDIT:** I updated my kernel version from 4.19 to 5.1.14 and it *seems* to have fixed the issue. Usually on a single day it might crash/mess up the filesystem at least 5 to 6 times but in 2 days I only had to reboot one time.

My laptop is an Acer Predator Helios 300, Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ, 16GiB RAM, NVIDIA GTX1060 6GB (nvidia-driver-410) running Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows in dual-boot (although I almost never used Windows).

Ubuntu crashes randomly. I do web development and usually after 40 minutes or so, my laptop starts getting slower. Opening the shell takes longer, file writes are slower, mouse starts getting slow etc... After some time it just freezes completely. I have to force reboot it.

When I reboot it, it brings up `initramfs` where I do `fsck /dev/sda2`, say `yes` to all fixes until it finishes the `reboot` it.

Sometimes the reboot works, sometimes the filesystem gets remounted in `readonly`, even after fixing, as soon as the OS loads. Sometimes I have to do this upto **5 times in a row**. Needless to say, this is really frustrating me and slowing down my word (I am a web-dev).

`smartctl` output:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       947
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2143
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       78
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       299
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   068   037   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 13/63)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   095   095   001    Old_age   Offline      -       5
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17550641040
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       550398567
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       440978387
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       2041
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

What should I do?

Also I should mention that I didn't put the `kernel.log`s because I have something wrong with my touchpad that fills up the `kernel.log` with lines like these:

```
Jun 24 10:06:40 mehdisaffar-Predator-G3-571 kernel: [24335.295971] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0501:01: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

Comment: Do you have Docker or similar tools installed maybe? I heard of issues like this in relation to running Docker containers and some specific kernel versions. Always worth trying to upgrade to 19.04 to get newer kernels, or booting an older kernel version instead for a while.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes I have Docker installed although I rarely used/didn't really need to use it so far. I can try disabling it and see what happens.

Comment: It could be caused by a bad RAM stick. Booting 5 times in a row could be that the laptop keeps trying to boot with the RAM and finally gives up the 5th time and boots without the bad RAM stick. If this is true, Sysinfo (*sysinfo*) from the default Ubuntu repositories will show less RAM than is actually present in the laptop.

Comment: @karel Could be, but I have never had any problem related to filesystem corruption when under Windows (although I prefer Linux for development anytime). But Windows is running under and NVMe SSD while Ubuntu under a regular SSD. Could that be the reason?

Comment: SSDs don't usually have any problems except that the BIOS/UEFI settings sometimes (not usually) have to be changed in order for the OS that is installed on the SSD to be able to boot properly.

Comment: Is the SMART data that you show for the SSD (or the NVMe)? In Windows, did you install a driver to allow you to read/write to linux partitions?

Comment: @heynnema It is for the SSD that Ubuntu is installed on. Also I have updated the kernel from 4.19 to 5.1.14. Hopefully it fixes the issue but I am not too hopeful. About Windows I am not completely sure but I think I had some Tux file explorer something like that that allows me to only read from a linux filesystem.

Comment: @MehdiSaffar status please...

Comment: @MehdiSaffar status please...

Comment: @MehdiSaffar please check the updated BIOS info in my answer. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

**Check your SSD firmware**

It's very important to check the firmware version of your SSD (and your NVMe). In the terminal, do `sudo lshw -C disk`. It'll tell you the firmware version, and then you can go to the manufacturer's website and check for updates.

**Check your BIOS**

In the terminal, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and then go to the manufacturer's website to check for a newer BIOS.

Current BIOS is 1.22 dated 4/1/2019. See https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7213?b=1

**Make sure you have enough swap**

In the terminal, do `free -h` and make sure that you have at least a 2G swap partition or /swapfile.

**Check your cabling**

If the SSD is an internal drive, check the condition of the SATA cables and assure that they're tightly connected at both ends.

If the SSD is external, assure that you're using a USB3 port if the drive enclosure is USB3. Also keep in mind that the USB cable, enclosure, and enclosure power supply can also be suspects.

**Check your memory**

Go to http://www.memtest.org or https://www.memtest86.com/ (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 of the tests to confirm that the memory is good.